# js not loading properly in backend product edit while click on show/hide of description field magento 2.2.4 production mode

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

This issue specific to production mode of Magento 2.2.4.

Js is appending in product edit url like :

> base_url/admin/catalog/product/edit/id/57473/set/12/key/0225361c458609d4c7d2cd0ecaa40b96dab87a5fef098bddd1b575ee3ce6b474/type/simple/store/0/back/edit//themes/advanced/editor_template.js

Here our edit URL is

> base_url/admin/catalog/product/edit/id/57473/set/12/key/0225361c458609d4c7d2cd0ecaa40b96dab87a5fef098bddd1b575ee3ce6b474/type/simple/store/0/back/edit/

js file is `/themes/advanced/editor_template.js`.

I have tried to change production mode to developer it worked there.

Also tried to re-deployment, di-compile and also checked file permission, it is already in 777.

Please let me know if some faced this issue earlier.